# How to generalize using C# generics?

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

I'm trying to make a structure that can parse various file formats into entity type objects for storage in the database.

I want to make the code as easy as possible to read and extend with further file formats and entity types independently of each other.

In general I have a fileparser, which consumes a file and returns a DTO model. This DTO model is then consumed by a converter, which returns a database entity object. Both the parser, the converter and the DTO model extends abstract classes to avoid code duplication. The process is conducted by a class called Service.

Here's the essence of the code:

```
class Service
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var model = new DerivedModel<DerivedRow>();
        var parser = new DerivedParser<DerivedModel<DerivedRow>>(model);
    }
}

class DerivedModel<TRow> : AbstractModel<DerivedRow>
    where TRow : DerivedRow
{
    public override DerivedRow NewRow()
    {
        return new DerivedRow();
    }
}

abstract class AbstractModel<TRow>
{
    public abstract TRow NewRow();
}

class DerivedRow : AbstractRow
{
}

abstract class AbstractRow
{
}

class DerivedParser<TModel> : AbstractParser<TModel>
    where TModel : AbstractModel<AbstractRow>
{
    public DerivedParser(TModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public override TModel Parse()
    {
        var row = Model.NewRow();
        return Model;
    }
}

abstract class AbstractParser<TModel>
{
    public TModel Model { get; protected set; }

    public abstract TModel Parse();
}
```

The typechecker complains on THIS line of code in the Service class:

> var parser = new DerivedParser<DerivedModel<DerivedRow>>(model);

The error is:

> Error  CS0311  The type 'Sandbox.GenericTest.DerivedModel<Sandbox.GenericTest.DerivedRow>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'DerivedParser<TModel>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Sandbox.GenericTest.DerivedModel<Sandbox.GenericTest.DerivedRow>' to 'Sandbox.GenericTest.AbstractModel<Sandbox.GenericTest.AbstractRow>'.

I have tried using some interfaces in combination with the abstract classes, but this only complicated things.

Any suggestions? Is what I'm trying to do even possible in C# this way?

Comment: While the duplicate does not answer how to do what you want, it answers why you cannot

Comment: I believe you can solve it by giving the DerivedParser 2 generic types, one generic type for the model and one generic type for the row. Although i'm not sure.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It looks like it was actually possible (see the answer), but thankyou for the Covarianca/Contravariance reference! :)

Comment: @bramve You are partially right! :) Take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass **TModel** and the error goes away. 
You need to mention the type of Model to AbstractParser. Once you pass that error goes away.
Here is the code

```
class Service
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var model = new DerivedModel<DerivedRow>();
        var parser = new DerivedParser<DerivedModel<DerivedRow>, DerivedRow>(model);
    }
}

class DerivedModel<TRow> : AbstractModel<DerivedRow>
    where TRow : DerivedRow
{
    public override DerivedRow NewRow()
    {
        return new DerivedRow();
    }
}

abstract class AbstractModel<TRow> where TRow : AbstractRow
{
    public abstract TRow NewRow();
}

class DerivedRow : AbstractRow
{
}

abstract class AbstractRow
{
}



class DerivedParser<TModel, TRow> : AbstractParser<TModel, TRow>
        where TModel : AbstractModel<TRow> where TRow : AbstractRow
{
    public DerivedParser(TModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public override TModel Parse()
    {
        var row = Model.NewRow();
        return Model;
    }
}

abstract class AbstractParser<TModel, TRow> where TRow : AbstractRow
{
    public TModel Model { get; protected set; }

    public abstract TModel Parse();
}
```